# How to set the WebSocket subprotocol in js

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Am creating a client websocket with javascript andam lost where to put this key "Sec-WebSocket-Key : dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==" 
Trying to do with the code below but I get the error

***index.html:14 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol 'dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==' is invalid.
    at WebSocketTest (file:///C:/handshake/index.html:14:16)
    at :1:1***

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {
            
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               // Let us open a web socket
               //var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.104:9001");
      var ws = new WebSocket("wss://192.168.1.104:9001", "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==");
                ws.onopen = function() {
                  //test open connectin
      alert("Connection Established...");
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };
    
               ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };
    
               ws.onclose = function() { 
                  
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {
              
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
      </script>
```

```html
  <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
   <p> Tested </p>
      </div>
      
   </body>
```

```
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda strange that the title of this question talks about setting a WebSocket subprotocol but the text of the question and the code excerpt are concerned with the WebSocket security key.  Those are two completely different things.

The [JavaScript WebSocket object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) provides no access to the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header.  That header is generated internally by the browser's WebSocket implementation.  From JavaScript you can't set that key and you can't read that key.

The second argument to the WebSocket constructor lets you specify content (one or more subprotocol names) for the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header, not for `Sec-WebSocket-Key`.  That's why the error message complains about being given an invalid subprotocol name when you pass `"dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=="` as that argument.

Comment: So the server require that key while the js client sends the request. How can I solve that.

Comment: Does the server require that specific key value?  There's no way in to force the browser to send that exact key.  The browser will make up its own key and will send that made-up key to the server.  The error is thrown because `"dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=="` is not a legal subprotocol name.  Subprotocol names are not allowed to contain the "=" character.

Comment: okay,  I have removed the key value there but a new error is thrown.  failed: "Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
WebSocketTest @ index.html:14
(anonymous) @ VM127:1"

Comment: I'd look in the server log for clues.  Are you certain that the server expects a TLS (SSL) encrypted WebSocket (`wss:`) and not just a plaintext WebSocket (`ws:`) ?  If that all looks OK then I would use Wireshark to examine the network traffic.

Comment: Either way when I use "ws" or "wss" it give the same "Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE"